# How to get the 'momentum space' equation from the Proca equation via $p_\mu \leftrightarrow i \hbar \partial_\mu$?

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, fourier-transform, propagator

In Introduction to Elementary Particles (page 370, Second Edition) Griffiths writes that

$$\left[ \left(-p^2 + (mc)^2 \right) g_{\mu \nu} + p_\mu p_\nu \right] A^\nu=0$$

derives from

$$\partial_\mu (\partial^\mu  A^\nu - \partial^\nu A^\mu ) + \left( \frac{mc}{\hbar} \right)^2 A^\nu = 0$$

from the prescription $$p_\mu \leftrightarrow i \hbar \space\partial_\mu . \tag{7.5}$$

[Griffiths uses Minkowski sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$.] It seems that $p^2 =p_\mu p^\mu \leftrightarrow \partial_\mu \partial^\mu $ but then why the negative sign? (Edit: I think, from the imaginary $i$'s which explains why the other term changes signs too)

Also, should $p^\nu \leftrightarrow  i \hbar \space\partial^\nu $ rather than $p_\nu$ as it seems to here?

And why is $g_{\mu\nu}$ there?

The propagator is $i$ times the inverse of $[(-p^2 + (mc)^2 )g_{\mu \nu} + p_\mu p_\nu]$. So I've included the "propagator" tag.

Comment: Have you tried making the replacement and carrying out the differentiation/derivation of the result?

Comment: @Triatticus Yes, I'm going to try again now. I'm going to expand all the sums out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the correct prescription *is* $p^{\nu} \leftrightarrow  i \hbar \space\partial^\nu$, and that is exactly what we have here. The metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$ you have also inquired about is precisely what we use to raise this index. Multiplying your first equation by $g^{\mu\beta}$ (which is simply the inverse of $g_{\mu\nu}$) and dividing through by $\hbar^2$, we find
\begin{equation} \left(\partial_{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha} + \mu^2 \right)\delta_{\nu}^{\beta}A^{\nu} - g^{\mu\beta}\partial_\mu \partial_\alpha A^{\alpha} =0,\end{equation} where i have defined $\mu=mc/\hbar$ for convenience, renamed the repeated index $\nu$ in the last term to $\alpha$, and used the definition of inverse tensor, which gives $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\beta}=\delta_{\nu}^{\beta}$. You seem to have figured out already that the sign changes come from the $(i)^2$. By definition of the metric tensor, we have $g^{\mu\beta}\partial_{\mu}=\partial^{\beta}$, and thus
\begin{equation} \partial_\alpha\partial^{\alpha}A^{\beta} -\partial_\alpha\partial^\beta A^{\alpha}  + \mu^2A^{\beta} =0,\end{equation},
where I have used the symmetry of partial derivatives to write $\partial_\alpha\partial_\beta=\partial_\beta\partial_\alpha$

Comment: Thanks, I'm just a little unsure of one thing. Isn't the metric inverse usually written $g^{\mu \beta}$ for $g_{\beta\nu}$ (so that the inner components match)?

Comment: Since the metric tensor is always symmetric, we have $g^{\mu\beta}=g_{\beta\mu}$, so it doesn't really matter in this case.  But the order is important for other tensors, so it is indeed better to write them as you did.